# I dont see NFT collection under my account on open sea, how can I customize it?

Tags: nft, royalties, opensea

I deployed this smart contract "https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0x26997e6b564a1be38bcce84955276ed3ac348600" on rinkeby network and trying to create my collection page by importing the smart contract address here: https://testnets.opensea.io/get-listed/step-two

and this is my collection page I then get: https://testnets.opensea.io/collection/testwolf-v2

but, I dont see this collection on this link: https://testnets.opensea.io/collections Its empty

I need to see my collection in this, so I can customize it for royalties. Please help.

Thanks,

Fariha

Comment: Have you found the reason? You asked the question 4 months ago. Has it been listed?